# NSPersistentCloudKitContainer stop sync when CKErrorDomain 12 error occurred

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, ckerror

My app uses NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to implement Coredata and iCloud synchronization data

Recently, I received feedback from online users about data synchronization errors, and the error code is CKErrorDomain 12 .

In the App, I use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification` to monitor the synchronization status, the following is the specific code

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification)
            .sink(receiveValue: { notification in
                if let cloudEvent = notification.userInfo?[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventNotificationUserInfoKey]
                    as? NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.Event {
                    let event = SyncEvent(from: cloudEvent) 
                }
            })
            .store(in: &disposables)
```

When the user feedbacks that the data cannot be synchronized, it can be seen from the above code that an error occurred when CoreData + iCloud was exporting data.

At the same time, cloudKitEvent.error does not contain any error information, only `CKErrorDomain 12` this information, I don’t know how to troubleshoot the error at all.

What's even more frightening is that when the `CKErrorDomain 12` error occurs, the app's synchronization service will stop immediately. Trying to restart the app or restart the phone, and turn off iCloud synchronization in the system, will not make the synchronization service work again.

Only uninstalling and reinstalling can completely solve this problem, but users will also lose some data after uninstalling, because when the error occurs, any data generated by the user has not been successfully synchronized to iCloud, so these data will be lost after uninstalling.

The following is the code for CoreDataStack initialization

```
private func setupContainer(allowCloudKitSync: Bool) -> NSPersistentCloudKitContainer {
    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: containerName)
    let privateStoreURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent(privateStoreName)
    let privateDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: privateStoreURL)
    let privateOpt = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: identifier)
    
    privateDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    privateDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    
    "allowCloudKitSync = \(allowCloudKitSync)".debugLog("CoreDataStack")
    
    if allowCloudKitSync {
        privateDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = privateOpt
    } else {
        privateDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
    }

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [privateDescription]
    
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self] (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            self?.dbStatePublish.send(.loadError)
            #if DEBUG
            "Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)".debugLog("CoreDataStack")
            #endif
        } else {
            if storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions == nil {
                self?.coreDataState = .local
            } else {
                self?.coreDataState = .cloud
            }

            "load coredata status = \(String(describing: self?.coreDataState))".debugLog("CoreDataStack")
        }
    })
    
    //let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptions()        
    //try? container.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: options)

    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    container.viewContext.transactionAuthor = appTransactionAuthorName

    // Pin the viewContext to the current generation token and set it to keep itself up to date with local changes.
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    do {
        try container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
    } catch {
        fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to pin viewContext to the current generation:\(error)")
    }
    
    // Observe Core Data remote change notifications.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(storeRemoteChange(_:)),
                                           name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange,
                                           object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    
    return container
}
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Hope to get your help, thank you!

Comment: Seems to be `CKError.code.invalidArguments`. I don't know why, it stops though. There could be a "time" before it works again without needing to delete the app (like 24h ?)

Comment: @Larme Are you saying it will automatically fix after 24 hours? But according to my user feedback, this error has been happening for more than 20 days

Comment: I'm not sure at all, I was just guessing. But if your user encounter each time the same error before the grace period ends, it could explain it. I don't use CloudKit, so it's just assumptions.

Comment: Hi wanbo -- did you end up finding a solution?